# How to change core file size limit multiple times?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gnu

I would like to change core file size multiple times. I use following code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

void SetNewCoreSizeLimit(unsigned new_size) {
  rlimit resource_limit;
  resource_limit.rlim_cur = resource_limit.rlim_max = static_cast<rlim_t>(new_size);

  if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &resource_limit) == -1) {
    std::cerr << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
  }  
}

int main() {
  SetNewCoreSizeLimit(5);
  SetNewCoreSizeLimit(10);

  return 0;
}
```

The first call of setrlimit succeeds, the second one fails printing "Operation not permitted". Why?

Comment: I am curious: why do you code that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read *carefully* [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html):

> Each resource has an associated *soft* and *hard* limit.

You are changing both ones. Once the *hard* limit has been set, you cannot *raise* it (in an ordinary process):

> `EPERM`  An unprivileged process tried to *raise the hard limit*; the
>                 CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability is required to do this.
>
> `EINVAL` The value specified in resource is not valid; or, for
>                 setrlimit() or prlimit(): `rlim->rlim_cur` was greater than     `rlim->rlim_max`.

You probably should set *only* the *soft* limit:

```
 resource_limit.rlim_cur = static_cast<rlim_t>(new_size);
 resource_limit.rlim_max = RLIM_INFINITY;
```

Or query the *previous* limit with `getrlimit` and keep its `.rlim_max` field.

And your shell might have already set some limits (e.g. by using `ulimit` in your `~/.bashrc`).

You could try `cat /proc/self/limits` to query your limits in your shell (in an intelligible, textual, fashion)

Notice that a user with root access could still use [gcore(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html) anyway (or use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) thru `/proc/$(pidof yourapp)/maps` &  `/proc/$(pidof yourapp)/mem` etc... to get the data inside your process)